# Matlab computing correlation coefficents given a correlation matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I know there's a nice way to compute both the correlation matrix and the correlation coefficient using [`corr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/corr.html). However I'm already given a correlation matrix without the correlation coefficient. I don't want to recompute anything as far as covariances or correlation matrices.

What is the most efficient way to get the correlation coefficient?

Answer (score 1):

Is this a mathematical question rather than a Matlab question? If you already have the correlation matrix between two variables, the correlation coefficient is m_12/sqrt(m_11*m_22), where m_ij is the matrix element at row i and column j.

Comment: I'm asking if there is a function in matlab to do this for all or some of the correlation coefficients instead of rolling out my own

Comment: @pyCthon - If you already have most of the information, you'll need to compute it on your own.  These methods assume that most of the data is not known, which is sensible.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Use corrcoef(X). Have a look at [corrcoef](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/corrcoef.html)

Comment: `[r,p] = corrcoef(x)  % Compute sample correlation and p-values.` I'm already given the sample correlation, I don't want to recompute it because it will be expensive